# My RSA encryption and decryption function in JS doesn't work

Tags: javascript, encryption, rsa

My RSA decryption and encryption functions doesn't work properly.I don't know why. Please help.
So here's my code:

```
function decrypt(){
    var c = document.getElementById("c").value;
    var d = document.getElementById("d").value;
    var n = document.getElementById("n").value;

    var g=Math.pow(c, d);
    var m=g%n;

    var result = document.getElementById("m2");
    result.value=m;
}

function crypt(){
    var m = document.getElementById("m").value;
    var e = document.getElementById("e").value;
    var n2 = document.getElementById("n2").value;

    var l=Math.pow(m, e);
    var c=l%n2;

    var result = document.getElementById("c2");
    result.value=c;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean with "they don't work properly"? Please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Remember that JS numbers have a maximum integer value.

Comment: If i insert 10 and encrypt it with the public key 77/7 , i receive a result. Then if i decrypt the result with the private key 77/43 it returns 43 instead of 10.

Comment: Only the very smallest numbers can work correctly using your implementation. Even a modulus of 77 and a private exponent of 43 is way too large. A javascript Number is an IEEE 754 64-bit floating type. It can only exactly represent all the nonnegative integers <= 2\*\*53, after which there are gaps in the integers that can be represented. You will either have to use Javascript BigInts *and* write your own efficient modulus exponentiation function *or* use another existing and better designed bigint library.